# Cross domain xml error in dojox.form.Uploader

Tags: javascript, xml, http, dojo

I am using dojo file upload component in my project. Everything works well if I load the dojo.js library from my server, But if i use a CDN (another server) then the file upload component gives CROSS DOMAIN XML ERROR and does not work.

I know the problem is that the FLASH upload component is downloaded from another server (CDN) so the browser thinks that its a Cross domain xml request.

***Does any one has a way around for this issue?.*** Note that If I load dojo library from my server then every thing works fine, but overall page loading is very slow. That why we use CDN.

Comment: Have you tried adding a cross-domain policy file? It resides on _your_ server, and tells the flash player that it is allowed to access your domain. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: can you tell how to configure it on a windows server (2008 r2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually we have to create a file name crossdomain.xml and put it on root of of our domain. For example, Yahoo has used a google flash component and it is loaded from google server in yahoo website. So if that flash component try to communicate with yahoo server then the BROWSERS will try to download crossdomain.xml file from yahoo web server and see if google domain is permitted.

In my case I used DOJO CDN and after permitting in crossdomain.xml file the component is working perfectly. The file format looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM 
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="ajax.googleapis.com"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="yui.yahooapis.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

@CBroe Thanks for your valuable comments.